# I want to create a directory and upload images in i using php code. Here I have given my codet

Tags: php

```
if(empty($_FILES['img']['name']))
{
    $_SESSION['error']['fnm']="Please select Image";
}
else if(!($ext==".JPG"
        || $ext==".PNG"
        || $ext==".GIF"
        || $ext=="JPEG"
        || $ext==".BMP"))
{
    $_SESSION['error']['fnm']="Wrong type of image";
}
else if(file_exists("img/".$_FILES['img']['name']))
{
    $_SESSION['error']['fnm']="Image Already available";
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['error']))
{
    header("location:dbimage.php");
}
else{

    $fnm=time()."_".$_FILES['img']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"img/".$fnm);

    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","login");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"picture");

    $q="update picture
        set profile_pic='$fnm' where id=1" ;

    mysqli_query($link,$q);

    header("location:dbimage.php");
}
```

> In  this  'img'  folder  is  already  there.  I  want  to  make folder as  per  my  time()  function's  initial  first  4  digit's  (want to make four folders)  for  example  file  name  in  db  is 1518691864_download2.png  and  I  want  to  make  folders  1/5/1/8  and then  want  to  store  image  in  it  like 1/5/1/8/1518691864_download2.png.

Comment: I'm done with this...

Comment: can you add your answer here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this answer I have just completed it**

```
<?php
$fnm = time()."_".$_FILES['img']['name'];
$str = substr($fnm, 0, 4);
$strlen = strlen($str); 
$oldfolder = '';
for($i=$strlen;$i>0;$i--){
    $newfoldername = substr($str, -$i,1);
    $oldfolder = $oldfolder == '' ? $newfoldername : $oldfolder.'/'.$newfoldername;    
    if (!file_exists($newfoldername)) {
        if($i==$strlen){
            mkdir($newfoldername, 0777, true);
        } else {
            mkdir($oldfolder, 0777, true);
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Folder already exists <br/>";
    }
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$oldfolder."/".$fnm);
?>
```

Comment: I did the same @priyank.. and thank you for the answer as well.

Comment: @Jay i took little more time then you and give me up-vote if it work :)

Comment: definitely @priyank